# What is the purpose of the metal strip??

Tags: electrostatics

Context:

> Two large, flat metal plates are held parallel to each other and
>   separated by a distance $d$. They are connected together at their edge
>   by **a metal strip**. A thin plastic sheet carrying a surface charge
>   $\sigma$ per unit area is placed between the plates @ a distance
>   $\frac{1}{3}d$ from the upper plate.
>
> Call $\vec{E}_{1} $ and $\vec{E}_{2} $ the electric field near the
>   upper and lower plates respectively. What are  $\vec{E}_{1} $ and
>   $\vec{E}_{2} $?

What's the purpose of that metal strip? Would it affect the outcome? If so, how come? If not, why would it be mentioned in the question, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two plates were not connected together by a conducting material, like the metal strip, then this would not work as a capacitor.

My guess is that the metal strip symbolizes the conducting wires / lanes in a curcuit. They are simply trying to make the question sound more non-curcuit-like by calling it "two plates connected by a metal strip".

Comment: I see... TY for the explanation